# Checkout branch from origin/dev but do not track origin/dev

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have these lines in a bash script:

```
git checkout -b foo "origin/dev"
git push -u origin HEAD
```

what I want to do is create a new branch foo whose parent is origin/dev. (Correct my terminology please).

The problem is I get:

> ```
> Branch foo set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
> ```

What does that mean exactly? When I checkout foo and do git push, I want it to be pushed to a branch called foo on the remote. I thought when a local branch tracked a remote that when you pushed the branch it would to go to the tracking branch right?

Answer (score 2):

Branches do not have parent branches.

Branches *do* have *upstream* settings.  More specifically, each branch name (each local name of the form `refs/heads/name`) can have one (1) upstream, or not have an upstream.

When creating a branch with `git branch` or `git checkout -b`, if you choose to set the new branch's upstream at that time, Git prints out the message you quoted:

> ```
> Branch foo set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
> ```

This means that your `refs/heads/foo` has, as its one allowed upstream, the name `origin/dev`.

When using `git checkout -b` to create a branch, if you don't want the new branch to have an upstream, either:

- Don't name a valid upstream.  For instance:

  ```
  git checkout -b foo
  ```

  creates new branch `foo` pointing to the current commit, without setting an upstream for new branch `foo`.
- Use the `--no-track` option to tell Git not to set the upstream, even though you are using a name that is suitable to install as the upstream:

  ```
  git checkout --no-track -b foo origin/dev
  ```

However, there's no problem with having `foo`'s upstream set to `origin/dev` because you can *change* or *remove* this setting *at any time* using `git branch`:

```
git branch --unset-upstream foo
```

will remove the current upstream from `foo`, while:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/xyzzy foo
```

will set `foo`'s upstream to `origin/xyzzy`.  The one constraint with this last command is that `origin/xyzzy` must actually exist.

(Note that very old versions of Git do not have `--set-upstream-to`.  Instead, they have `--set-upstream`, which does the same thing, but requires that the order of arguments be swapped.  This turned out to be a common source of mistakes, so modern Git deprecates the old `--set-upstream` option, replacing it with `--set-upstream-to` which is easier to use correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

> Branch foo set up to track remote branch dev from origin.

it's mean your local `foo` branch is tracking remote `dev` branch. So, `git push` will push to `dev` branch. You need to change the tracking branch to remote `foo` branch.

One of the way is following:

---

Push to remote `foo` branch from local `foo` branch:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:foo
```

Set the upstream of local `foo` branch to remote `foo` branch:

```
$ git branch foo --set-upstream-to origin/foo

Or,
$ git branch foo -u origin/foo
```

Now, local `foo` branch is tracking to 'remote foo' branch. So, just `git push` will push to remote foo branch.